# Hide my friends activities on Facebook

Tags: facebook

On Facebook I very frequently see activities in my feed where my friend likes or comments on another person's post but that person isn't my friend. Can I hide such posts from my news feed?

Comment: On a per-post basis, or for everything like that going forward?

Comment: @AlE. - everything

Answer (score 1):

You are just seeing your friend activity, whatever they do, you see that in your feed. Because you are following your friend. Just stop following your friend, you will not see his/her activity on your feed but you still be friend.

Go to friend's timeline, click on "Following" tab, you will see "Unfollow frinedName", click on that. Now you both are friends but you have stopped following your friend, so you will not see his/her activity on your feed.

Comment: This solves the problem with a sledge hammer. By doing this, you will also miss activity you may be interested in.

Comment: Yes, true, but there is no other way available at this time.

Comment: I have a similar question asked here: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/99843/how-can-i-stop-likes-of-other-people-from-appearing-on-my-feed Because I would like to see content created by my friends, and not their likes.