# How can I stop likes of other people from appearing on my feed?

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline

I think the subject says it all.
I have some few friends and I would like to see content they create, but I'm not interested in seeing their likes. Any chance I could hide one and see other?
Also if it's possible i would like to change this on a per profile setting.

Comment: Presumably you're talking about a smartphone app? This site is really only about the web interface.

Comment: Ok,changing the question.

Comment: Related--> http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/85805/87130